# How to use data from meteor subscription

Tags: reactjs, meteor, subscription

I added extra fields to the root in users collection of Meteor app and can't access them from react.
Here is publication:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
   // This code only runs on the server

 Meteor.publish('currentUserInfo', () => {
     if (!this.userId) {
         return this.ready();
     }

     return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
 }); }
```

Here is subscription:

```
export default createContainer(()=>{
    Meteor.subscribe('currentUserInfo');

    return {
        currentUser: ???,
```

How can I pass subscription data through props?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.user()

or

Meteor.users.findOne( Meteor.userId() )

Comment: Do not work. It returns only predefined properties,  like username and email.

Comment: `Meteor.users.findOne( Meteor.userId() )
Object { _id: "Lm5LiXAt4pPFszHhC", emails: Array[1] }`

Comment: You right, but problem was tired with publish code, which was not executed at server for some strange reason

Comment: glad you figured it out :)